# Trouble adding compiler to windows path

Tags: c++, c, gcc, mingw

I'm having a seemingly silly problem with my gcc compiler.  I have installed MinGW at location C:\MinGW... and I have added C:\MinGW\bin to my windows path.  However, when I got to the command prompt and type gcc --version... it doesn't recognize it.  I have to cd manually to the bin before it will recognize it.

When I go back to my windows path it shows it there... so I'm not sure what the problem is.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Have you restarted your command terminal since you modified the path?  Can you see the directory listed if you type `PATH`?

Comment: Yes I see the directory listed when I type path.  I've restarted my computer as well.

Comment: That's strange, can you output your `PATH` for us to see?

Comment: What do you get when you execute that gcc command? A "not found" error, or another installation of the compiler?

Comment: I was setting the path by right clicking on properties... then clicking advanced system settings, enviro variables.. etc.  I will take a look at RapidEE... thanks!

Comment: @TED : I get 'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command... etc.

Comment: By the way, I used the RapidEE tool and found it to be very handy - thanks.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at Eveditor (http://eveditor.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you set the path?  You should set it from ***Control Panel->System->Advanced->Environment Variables***. The change will affect newly opened command consoles only.

If it then does not work, in the console, when you enter the command `path` does the displayed path list include your path?  Is it correct?

Are ther other GNU toolchain paths that appear before the mingw one (Cygwin for example)?

Does the path contain spaces?  Some ported GNU tools do not always work correctly with paths containing spaces.

Comment: Spaces shouldn't matter, because it sounds as if the problem is to do with Windows not even locating the executable in the first place.

Comment: @Oli: True, but to check may avoid other problems later, I thought I'd cover all the bases from the start.

Comment: Actually it turned out to be a space.  I didn't realize that would be a problem either.

Answer (score 2):

Have you started a new command window? The path doesn't change in existing windows as you change the path through environment variables.

Do you see the desired path in the output of:

```
  C:\> echo %PATH%
```

Comment: Yes, actually I tried restarting my computer a few times but no luck.  And echo %path% gives what I would expect for the path.

Comment: Just entering the `path` command is sufficient.  @Kent: It gives what you expect, so post it in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help everybody.  I finally noticed there was a space before my C... ugh.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Clifford - thanks. I use the echo pattern everywhere, so I don't have to think about it.